# Assign child to parent with objects in the same method

Tags: apex, visualforce, master-detail

I need to assign the child of a parent record that is in the same method. Would I have to insert it before assigning the Id to a parent?

```
        //Add row method for both lists
    public PageReference add_record(){
        //Recipient fields
        Recipient__c anotherRecipient = new Recipient__c();
        anotherRecipient.Name = rec.Name;
        anotherRecipient.Last_Name__c = rec.Last_Name__c;
        anotherRecipient.School__c = rec.School__c;
        anotherRecipient.Specialty__c = rec.Specialty__c;

        
    
        //Scholarship fields
        Scholarship_Award__c anotherScholarship = new Scholarship_Award__c();
        anotherScholarship.Award__c = sch.Award__c;
        anotherScholarship.Year__c = sch.Year__c;
        anotherScholarship.School__c = sch.School__c;
        
        //Tried this - isn't going to work
        //anotherScholarship.Recipient__c = rec.Id;

        //Add to lists
        recList.add(anotherRecipient);
        anotherScholarship.Recipient__c = rec.Id;
        anotherScholarship.School__c = rec.School__c;
        schList.add(anotherScholarship);
        
        return null;
    }
```

BTW I have finally solved the issue I was having displaying 2 objects in the same `pageBlockTable` by just having 2 tables side by side - thank you to everyone who answered, learnt a lot anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do them together but you need to use an External Id field.  A good place to start is probably here: https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2012/02/cascade-insert-with-external-id-fields.html